# Announcement command Trouble

Tags: python, discord

So I'm using this code to make my announcements

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True, aliases=[ 'a', 'announce' ])
async def announce_command(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, send a title in 60 seconds, to begin embed builder!",delete_after=45)

  def check(m: discord.Message):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
  
  try:
    titlemsg = await bot.wait_for(event = 'message', check = check, timeout= 10 )
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, State a description.", delete_after=45)
    msg= await bot.wait_for(event = 'message', check = check, timeout= 40)
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, State a Url, if you want a thumbnail added.",delete_after=45)
    UrlThmsg= await bot.wait_for(event= 'message', check = check, timeout= 10)

  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, you didn't send any message that meets the check in this channel for 60 seconds..", delete_after=45)
    return
  else:
    embed = d.Embed(title = f"{titlemsg.content}", description = f"{msg.content}", color = 0xFFFFFF)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = f"{UrlThmsg.content}")
    embed.set_footer(text = f'Annouced By {ctx.author}')

    
    await ctx.send('@everyone', embed = embed)
```

I wanted to make UrlTHmsg = a option event and if no one puts anything in it will say something like a thumbnail wont be added and move onto the next event without stopping the embed. If anyone can help me that would be great. This is discord.py btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `finally:` to execute code regardless of the exception. Also it would be better to declare a dictionary and then check the existence of a specific key to avoid an exception when you try to use an undeclared variable (or you can just declare your variables before `try:`):

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True, aliases=[ 'a', 'announce' ])
async def announce_command(ctx):
  await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, send a title in 60 seconds, to begin embed builder!",delete_after=45)

  def check(m: discord.Message):
    return m.author.id == ctx.author.id and m.channel.id == ctx.channel.id
  
  announce_info = {}

  try:
    announce_info['title'] = await bot.wait_for(event = 'message', check = check, timeout= 10 )
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, State a description.", delete_after=45)
    announce_info['description'] = await bot.wait_for(event = 'message', check = check, timeout= 40)
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, State a Url, if you want a thumbnail added.",delete_after=45)
    announce_info['thumbnail'] = await bot.wait_for(event= 'message', check = check, timeout= 10)

  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send(f"**{ctx.author}**, you didn't send any message that meets the check in this channel for 60 seconds..", delete_after=45)
    return
  finally:
    if announce_info.get('title') and announce_info.get('description'):
      embed = d.Embed(title = f"{announce_info['title'].content}", description = f"{announce_info['description'].content}", color = 0xFFFFFF)
      embed.set_thumbnail(url = f"{announce_info['thumbnail'].content}") if announce_info.get('thumbnail') else None
      embed.set_footer(text = f'Annouced By {ctx.author}')

    
      await ctx.send('@everyone', embed = embed)
```

Comment: I am moving this code over to a cog and for line 2 its saying invalid syntax and I dont know why. I am using replit. I re did atbot.commands to atcommands.command in asynce (ctx) changed that to (self, ctx: commands.Context). If you could give me a small explanation on why this is happening that would be awesome.

Comment: nvm i some how forgot to add a ) to one of the lines. Thank you for helping me